# I can't see MSYS home directory under Windows 7's file explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, mingw

I'm using MSYS (MinGW UNIX environment) to get a working UNIX-like environment on my Windows 7 workstation. When I start the MinGW shell, I can see that my home directory is `/home/oded.a`,  and running `mount` shows me that it comes from `msys\1.0` under the MinGW installation directory.

It works fine and I can put files there, write and read them using the MSYS environment utilities and shells, but when I open the Windows 7 file explorer and browse to `msys\1.0`, I can't see a directory named `home` and I would really like to be able to access my MSYS home files using Windows tools. Any idea where the home directory is actually stored?

This is the output of `mount` on my system:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\msys\1.0 on /usr type user (binmode,noumount)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\msys\1.0 on / type user (binmode,noumount)
C:\Users\oded.a\AppData\Local\Temp on /tmp type user (binmode,noumount)
c: on /c type user (binmode,noumount)
q: on /q type user (binmode,noumount)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$ pwd -W
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/Steven
```

Comment: Thanks. I no longer have this setup, but this is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh, `-W` option for `pwd`? Nice. This revealed that my MINGW home is the same as my Windows User home, but the keygen still have not placed the SSH keys inside `.ssh` directory, it was just laying in the home root.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a case that MinGW/MSYS does create home folder in  `~/msys/1.0/home/user`  (`user` is my user name)

The following is what I discovered.

`MinGW/MSYS` usually creates a home folder under `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/user` if you installed them as usual (accepting the defaults) and you executed `msys.bat` successfully. However, it does not create it where you expect if you happened to have an environment variable called `HOME`.

- Optionally, first check your home folder by `$pwd -W`    ($ is a command prompt.)
- Remove the environment variable called `HOME`. (It does not mess up Windows.")
- Reboot
- Execute `msys.bat` again.
- Optionally, now check where your home folder by `$pwd -W`
- Note: Don't need to reinstall `MinGW/MSYS`.

(a debtor)<><